# How to extract a single (column/row) value from a dataframe using PySpark?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Here's my spark code. It works fine and returns 2517. All I want to do is to print "2517 degrees"...but I'm not sure how to extract that 2517 into a variable. I can only display the dataframe but not extract values from it. Sounds super easy but unfortunately I'm stuck! Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

```
df = sqlContext.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").option("delimiter", "\t").load("dbfs:/databricks-datasets/power-plant/data")

df.createOrReplaceTempView("MyTable")

df = spark.sql("SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT AP) FROM MyTable")

display(df)
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

here is the alternative:

```
df.first()['column name']
```

it will give you the desired output. you can store it in a variable.

Answer (score 9):

I think you're looking for `collect`. Something like this should get you the value:

```
df.collect()[0]['count(DISTINCT AP)']
```

assuming the column name is `'count(DISTINCT AP)'`

Answer (score 5):

If you want to extract value in specific row and column:
`df.select('column name').collect()[row number][0]`
for example `df.select('eye color').collect()[20][0]`